# How can I add a startup parameter to a favorited application in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with the default GNOME Desktop and I want to add a startup parameter when starting an application from the launcher/dock (e.g., add UI scaling to Chrome).

In Unity, I could edit the corresponding `.desktop` file but I don't know how to do it in GNOME since I can't find the links in the launcher anyway. Editing the `.desktop` file has the desired effect when starting from the dash but not from the dock.

I would be very grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: What happens if you 'Remove from Favourites' first, then make changes to the `.desktop` file, and finally 'Add to Favourites' again?

Comment: When I remove Chrome from favorites and open it from the activities, the scaling parameter is applied. Then I add it back to the favorites, and it is no longer applied.